# Video editing without media library

Tags: c#, multimedia, video-editing

Is there a way to edit videos using c# without using a media library eg. Microsoft Expression Encoder etc.

Just need to be able to cut out unwanted parts  or insert other videos into a specified time of the original video.

Can I edit the raw video file by perhaps converting it into a binary file and then cutting/pasting the code?

Comment: Why the requirement not to use any external libraries?

Comment: All files are binary files. If you understand the structure of the video file, then of course it's possible. But the question is: why would you reinvent the wheel?

Comment: If you haven't any background about that, you can't. It is not as simple as removing some bytes from a *binary* file.

Comment: Can you, yes.  Will you be able to, no.

Comment: @Servy Well, given all we know is this is `user3790147` he/she *might* be able to. But it will take a *great* deal of work.

Comment: @drew_w If they have to ask this question, they won't be able to do it.  The people capable of doing such a thing would already know that such a thing is possible.

Comment: @Servy Fair enough. I was mostly just playing devil's advocate : )

Comment: You can try to process the video's raw bits, but you will ending up digging deep into video formats binary headers, frame rates codification, video compression, compression algorithms... the amount of work involved will be simply unpractical. Please don't do it!

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I have a year to research and implement it. Was trying to decide whether to use a library or to code it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most video formats have a container and a codec--that might be a good place to start

http://www.pitivi.org/manual/codecscontainers.html

If one were interested in implementing a program modifying video sans libraries a good place to start might be looking at the existing open source video libraries(eg FFMPEG https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html ) as a reference

Answer (score 1):

No there is no way to edit a video without using anything that would be considered a "library". You either must write your "library" or use a existing 3rd party one.

The only thing that could possibly not be thought of as a "library" is a full external tool that does what you want and your code would just be a front end GUI for it. For example writing a GUI front end for [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/).

Comment: To the downvoter, why do you consider my answer "not useful" and how could I improve it to be useful?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but technically you CAN edit it without a library. After all, the library developers wrote the code to do it without using another library for it. It just requires more effort than neccessary :). If he's knowledgeable enough, he could even do it with an hex editor.

Comment: As follow up, .Net itself is a "library".

Comment: @user1071777 I said that in my answer "**You either must write your "library"** or use a existing 3rd party one."